# i am looking for alternatives to compare 2 arrays, find equality and reassignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am somewhat new to react and javascript,

i have 2 arrays "apArr" and "newB", what i did was , i compare the two arrays ( by looping through each array of objects ) and find equality and then reassign

i manage to get my solution to work, but it will trigger complexity issue with eslint.

i am trying to find alternatives for my codes.

```
for (let i = 0; i < apArr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < newB.length; j++) {
    if (newB[j].columnHeader === apArr[i].columnHeader) {
      newB[j].defaultSelectedColumn = apArr[i].defaultSelectedColumn;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried googling high and low, but i still struggle with it, ... currently googling

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you mean by 'will trigger a complexity issue with eslint'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newB.forEach(bEl => {
  const equalElement = apArr.find(el => el.columnHeader == bEl.columnHeader)
  if(equalElement) {
    bEl.defaultSelectedColumn = equalElement.defaultSelectedColumn;
  }
})
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

```
apArr.map(element => {
  newB.map(subElement => {
    if(subElement.columnHeader === element.columnHeader) {
      subElement.defaultSelectedColumn = element.defaultSelectedColumn;
    }
  })
})
```

Anyhow u need to iterate fully over those two arrays, you don't have any option

Comment: Use map when you need to return mutated version of some array, for this kind of iteration use forEach

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use native find(), or filter() functions to do this job. Lodash library also have some interesting array comparing functions.